# react-native start FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run my first react native app.

I followed the "getting started" [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), and got to the run your app section.

However, when running `react-native start`, its memory usage when "Loading dependency graph" goes up until it reaches 100% and crashes.

I have 16 GB of ram, which I believe should be plenty enough, and could not find a similar problem googling it.

I use android studio to emulate a device with Pie API (Level 28)

Did I get anything wrong ?

```
C:\Users\username\AwesomeProject>react-native start                         


Looking for JS files in    C:\Users\username\AwesomeProject

Loading dependency graph... <--- Last few GCs --->

[5552:00000183131C4840]     3440 ms: Scavenge 73.3 (100.8) -> 58.7 (100.8) MB, 1.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF78F25982D]
    1: InternalFrame [pc: 00007FF78F1CDB0B] Security context: 0x02b761800911 <JSObject>
    2: next [000002B7618229A9](this=0x03d0580003f9 <JSGenerator>,0x0306a15cc069 <JSArray[18784]>)
    3: asyncGeneratorStep(aka asyncGeneratorStep) [0000008A0A6D9311] [C:\Users\username\AwesomeProject\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:193] [bytecode=000001EE8E830101 offset=11](this=0x01971d9404d1 <undef...

FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Comment: Downgrading to node v.12.4.0 maybe solve your issue

Comment: it solved the problem, thank you :)

Comment: Could you check the 'V' mark on my answer if it's settled with my help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a node problem, not a module problem.

Downgrading to node `v.12.4.0` maybe solve your issue